# Calculated items Zabbix

Tags: zabbix

I've only been studying Zabbix for two mere weeks. I've been finding my way around the software pretty well, yet I don't really seem to understand calculated items.

I'm sure you've heard it before. I want to monitor the ink level on one of my printers. I've already obtained the OID's that are bound to the ink levels. The value of 100% would be '8000'. So 50% would be 4000.

I've checked out the [Zabbix guide,](https://www.zabbix.com/documentation/3.4/manual/config/items/itemtypes/calculated) but that didn't really seem to help me out. I understand the concept it tries to explain, but I don't understand what exact parameters I should be using. This is what I have so far, which is obviously not working.

```
100*last("cyan")/last("8000")
```

I've created five seperate items, one for each colour and one that is simply the value '8000'. Could anyone give me a little bit of insight? I'd love to get more familiar with the software due to it's near endless possibilities!

Many thanks,

Thomas.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Item of just "8000" is most likely not needed. You said "obviously not working", but did not say how it fails. In any case, the following should work - assuming you have an item with key "cyan" and that item is getting values.

```
last(cyan)/80
```

You haven't specified what is your goal, but the above will return %, assuming 8000 is 100%.

So that's about calculated items. You actually don't need them if all you want is the value in % and the scale is the same for all of them. Instead of adding yet another item (the calculated one), do the calculation right in the original item - set the [custom multiplier](https://www.zabbix.com/documentation/3.4/manual/config/items/item#item_value_preprocessing) to 0.0125. This was configured differently in earlier versions of Zabbix, see the corresponding version in the manual if using something older than 3.4.

Comment: Thank you for your assistance. I wasn't aware that you could set the scale on items themselves. The calculated formula you posted was also working. Apologies for not stating what exactly wasn't working. I'll try to be more descriptive, next time.